# Swift compiler bug? Can't use "direct" as method name

Tags: swift, rabbitmq, swift3

Can someone please sanity-check me on this?  I made a Swift3/Obj-C project* with three tiny files:

ChannelSpy.swift :

```
import Foundation  
class ChannelSpy: RMQChannel {  
    func direct(_ name: String!) {}  
}
```

RMQChannel.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
@protocol RMQChannel  
- (void) direct:(NSString *)name;  
@end
```

Bridging-Header.h :

```
#import "RMQChannel.h"
```

But this won't compile!  Here's the error I'm getting:
  **Type 'ChannelSpy' does not conform to protocol 'RMQChannel'**
    Protocol requires function 'dirent' with type '(String!) -> Void'; do you want to add a stub?

```
/Proj/. . ./ChannelSpy.swift:2:7: error: type 'ChannelSpy' does not conform to protocol 'RMQChannel'  
class ChannelSpy: RMQChannel {  
      ^  
__ObjC.RMQChannel:2:17: note: protocol requires function 'dirent' with type '(String!) -> Void'; do you want to add a stub?  
    public func dirent(_ name: String!)  
                ^
```

What's this "dirent" stuff?  Am I (or the Rabbit* project) not allowed to use the name "direct"?  I googled this (extensively, of course) and I see vestiges of `#define direct dirent` in ancient BSD code remnants, but I'm sure that has nothing to do with anything.

* - Actually I'm trying to build the [RabbitMQ Client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/), while porting it to Swift 3 and OS X (which it doesn't officially support).  That is, the tests are written in Swift while the Rabbit library itself remains Objective-C.  I'm checking my fork into GitHub for the benefit of others needing RabbitMQ on OS X.

Comment: That `#define` line has everything to do with your issue. Every use of the work `direct` will be replaced by the word `direct`. Assuming of course that header file is getting processed as part of your code.

Comment: So do you think that <code>#define</code> could still be <code>#include</code>d in Apple's Swift/Obj-C/bridging compiler code?  I tried asking this on the Apple Developer Forum -- they're ultra slow to approve my post, and it's been two days!  Maybe they're embarrassed.

Comment: `#define direct dirent` is in `<sys/dir.h>` which most probably is included (indirectly) from Foundation. It is marked as "Backwards compatibility.". – That is nasty, but adding `#undef direct` directly before the @protocol definition would be a (hackish) workaround.

Comment: Great comment about #undef'ing it.  Thank you!

Comment: Another option is of course to rename your `direct` method to something less cryptic.

Comment: @rmaddy:  Unfortunately `direct` is in the RabbitMQ project!  I'm not involved there, beyond forking it.

Comment: You won't notice the "problem" within Objective-C code because *all* files go through the preprocessor. But not the Swift files ...

Comment: @MartinR: I think your suggestion is a viable fix, for now.  If you answer with that below, I'll mark it as "answered."  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system include file `<sys/dir.h>` defines:

```
/*
 * Backwards compatibility.
 */
#define direct dirent
```

I have no idea what that definition is needed for, but apparently
`<sys/dir.h>` is included (indirectly) from `Foundation.h`, so that
`direct` is substituted by `dirent` in all (Objective-)C code.

Therefore the protocol is exposed to Swift as

```
public protocol RMQChannel {
    public func dirent(_ name: String!)
}
```

If renaming the property is not possible then `undef`ing the macro
(*after* including the system headers) should be a viable workaround:

```
#undef direct
@protocol RMQChannel  
- (void) direct:(NSString *)name;  
@end
```